# Practice determining if sets are open, closed and determining their closure

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I've been doing practice with determining whether sets are open or closed and if they are not closed, finding their closure. Here are a few practice problems I've tried I was wondering if I could get some opinions on my logic / if their are simpler ways to view these. Any help would be much appreciated!

**1.** All $x \in (0, 1)$ except for $x = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$ for $n= 1, 2, \dots$

**Answer:** The set is not closed because it does not contain 1, which is an accumulation point of the set ($x_n =\frac{n}{n+1}, n = 1, \dots \in S$ converges to $1$).  The set is open because it is a union of open sets which is open, $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (1-\frac{1}{n}, 1 - \frac{1}{n+1})$.  Its closure $\bar S = [0,1]$

**2.** $S = \{1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \dots \}$

**Answer:** $S$ is not closed since $0 \notin S$ and $0$ is an accumulation point ($x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ for $n = 1, 2, \dots$ $\in S, x_n \rightarrow 0, n\rightarrow \infty)$. $S$ is not open because for $\epsilon > 0$ there is no open ball $B(1, \epsilon) \subseteq S$. The closure $\bar S = S \cup {0}.$

**3.** $S = $ positive integers $n = 1, 2, \dots$

**Answer:** $S$ is closed because $S^C$ is open because it is a union of open sets $(-\infty, 1) \cup \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (n, n+1).$ $S$ is not open because for $\epsilon > 0$ there is no open ball $B(1, \epsilon) \subseteq S$.

**4.** The rational numbers $r \in (0,1)$

**Answer:** $S$ is not closed because it does not contain $0$, which is an accumulation point ($x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ for $n = 2, \dots \in S$ and $x_n$ converges to $0$). $S$ is not open because for any $x$ and $\epsilon > 0$ the open ball $B(x, \epsilon)$ contains an irrational number and so $B(x, \epsilon) \not\subseteq S$. The closure $\bar S=[0,1].$

Comment: Everything looks good. You might like an equivalent condition for openness in question 1: For each $x \in S$ there is an open ball $B$ satisfying $x \in B \subseteq S$. Using this, you need not reconstruct all of $S$ as the union of open sets (though it is easy to do so), but instead simply focus on finding a small enough ball around $x$.

Comment: Is this because those points $x = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$ are isolated so we can always find a $\delta > 0$ distance between them for our open ball?

Comment: The points in the set $S = \{1- \frac{1}{n} : n = 1, 2, \dots \}$ are not isolated? If I list them though: $0, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{3} \dots$ these points seem separated by a decreasing distance so for any $x$ in between them you can choose $\epsilon_n = \min\{|x - (1 - \frac{1}{n})|, |x - (1-\frac{1}{n+1})| \} > 0$ so that $B(x, \epsilon_n) \cap S = \emptyset $. Perhaps I'm not aware of the definition of isolated.

Comment: I misunderstood your question on first reading. Your comments and understanding of isolation are correct. Apologies.